# Realm database class table has a limit?

Tags: android, realm, stetho

I just found out that realm has a limit of 250 objects
is there any way that i can make to exceed this limit

[image]

this is an image from stetho to check my database

Comment: no no i mean like i want to add more than 250 object to that table

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've had 36000 rows in my table before and it worked just fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This limit you experience is not the limit of Realm, but the **default** limit on Stetho. You can adjust this though.

Set the `withLimit()` on the stetho config:

For example

```
    Stetho.initialize(
            Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this)
                    .enableDumpapp(Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(this))
                    .enableWebKitInspector(RealmInspectorModulesProvider.builder(this)
                            .withLimit(1000)
                            .build())
                    .build());
```

It will now show rows 0-999

Comment: i have an error after 250 objects those objects dont get into my database

Comment: No it's not. I've had at least 700 rows in a single table before

Comment: @Kaung How do you check if they go in the database or not?

Comment: the problem was that some of my items cannot be found 
from the database so i try to check whether it is in the database or not and it was not in it

Comment: @Kaung maybe they are in the database, but you cannot see them because the stetho is only showing the first 250 items

Comment: thanks it doesnt have the limit of 250 my code just have another bug the make it can't find the item

Comment: RealmInspectorModulesProvider is not available in the current Stetho version (1.4.1)

Comment: @ATom yes it is. Maybe you are matching with a wrong version of realm?